# Title Clean-Up Week, September. 5th-11th

Tags: discussion, title

Based on the discussion over on another Meta post (*[How can we clarify question titles?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/863)*), I am declaring September 5-11 the first **Title Clean-Up Week**! I'm saying first because this is pretty much a test run. Some users thought it would be fun to gamify this, and I think it would too, but instead of wasting time coming up with gamification, **let's go on and get down to business**.

From September 5th to September 11th, please pay extra attention to question titles. Make sure they are **complete titles** that **accurately reflect the question being asked**. [This post from Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19999/should-question-titles-be-phrased-as-questions-a-straw-poll) does a good job of summing up what a great question title looks like.

**Any post that is edited will be bumped to the main page**, so in order to keep a flood of old questions from taking over the main page **please only edit questions as they are asked or as you interact with them**. If you are going to do something to a question that will bump it to the top anyway, go on and give that title a glance. This was [previously mentioned as the modus operandi of user matt wilkie](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-can-we-clarify-question-titles#comment1413_863), and I think it makes sense.

Of course if there is an old question that you think deserves to be bumped **in addition to** having its title edited, go on and edit it.

This is a very loose event; there's no real reason why this has to start tomorrow or end on the 11th. But lets see how much we can accomplish in a week, anyway! And no, there are no prizes, but there are a number of badges that are up for grabs:

- **[Archaeologist](https://gis.stackexchange.com/badges/82/archaeologist)**
- **[Copy Editor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/badges/49/copy-editor)**
- **[Editor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/badges/3/editor)**
- **[Excavator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/badges/83/excavator)**
- [**Proofreader**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/badges/80/proofreader)
- **[Strunk & White](https://gis.stackexchange.com/badges/12/strunk-white)**

A real event, with a more definitive time frame and goal-specific perks is still on the table. But let's try to focus on this intensely for a week!

Please ping me in the chatroom if you have any questions or suggestions.

Comment: Added a message (moderator tools) to ALL users of GIS_SE to look at this post.

Comment: @Mapperz Editing the title of a post about editing titles?! Whoah, things got really meta on Meta! :)

Comment: It's only the start but "let's go on and get down to business"

Comment: Did my [first one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32790/are-there-any-shapefile-based-gps-data-recorders) already :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm in. Too bad the posts will still be bumped — I saved a few for this occasion from the [low vote/high view count](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/859/does-gis-have-a-low-voting-problem#comment1395_860) review and they're ancient and uninteresting by definition. I guess I will dose them into the stream slowly, so nobody notices the poison I mean old posts.

Comment: You could save them for the "real event", presumably bumping will be disabled then.

Comment: Presumably is the key word, there. I have my fingers crossed but can't make any guarantees. If you want to edit (and therefore bump) those uninteresting questions, I don't see anything wrong with doing one every few days or so, possibly at a time when other new questions are filtering in so it gets pushed down a bit. But again, judgment call!

Comment: It can wait, they only take one tab-width of space. ;) If the second run happens without a solution, I'll just have better reasons to do it; if not, they will not be an issue.